# find the link in tables sql exercise

Tags: sql, oracle11g

so I'm stuck on this question where it says:

write a query  to retrieve a list of ALL departments in alphabetical order containing the columns   DEPARTMENT_ID , DEPARTMENT_NAME , LAST_NAME , FIRST_NAME where last_name and first_name are the name of the Manager of the Department wherever there is one.

I'm have the HR database using the departments, employees table what i have written so far is:

```
select department_id, department_name, e.last_name, e.first_name
from departments d, employees e
where e.department_id=d.department_id
and d.department_id=e.department_id
and d.manager_id=e.manager_id
having department_name = '%Manager%';
```

yet i can't figure it out, any tips will help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A having clause relates to a group by.  Where you have no group by, there is no meaning for a having clause.

You just need your join to get the record in the employees table for the manager.

```
select department_id, department_name, e.last_name, e.first_name
from departments d, employees e
where d.manager_id=e.id
```

Better is to use the newer join syntax,

```
select dept.department_id, dept.department_name, emp.last_name, emp.first_name
from departments dept
  inner join employees emp on dept.manager_id = emp.id
```

You don't need conditions for e.department_id=d.department_id and d.department_id=e.department_id, (for one thing these are redundant, so you would only need one if they were needed) because the employees.department_id field refers to the department the employee is in, and what you want is the manager employee record for the department.  The manager employee record for the department is represented as the foreign key to the primary key of the employee table.

Comment: you forgot about "alphabetical order" [ORDER BY department_name] :)

Comment: I don't see where there is a need for a UNION.  The inner join gives you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you...

```
`select e.first_name,e.last_name,d.department_id ,d.department_name from employees e,departmets d where d.manager_id=e.employee_id order by d.department_name;`
```

Comment: @user2145903:Dude...you need to print department details and it's manager names right,so manager details(company employees's) are stored in employee table,so simply I've joined these two tables based on manager_id from department table to employee_id in employees table so we can access corresponding details of the manager.